# Cannot concat in Google Data Studio CASE

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to create a new field that shows age range from a json-like string that is stored in `Targeting` field. However, it is not guaranteed that those data exist in that row.

Sample data (age_min/age_max doesn't always have to exist together, either can exist separately)

```
{"age_min":25,"age_max":45,"other_nonrelated":1234}
```

This is how I extract age_min/age_max

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Targeting, '.*\"age_min\":(\\d*).*')
```

After trying to play around with CASE function, it seems like the I cannot use `REGEXP_EXTRACT`. So I created new fields for age_min and age_max as `Targeting Age Min` and `Targeting Age Max`.

Now I just have to make sure that both `Targeting Age Min` and `Targeting Age Max` are not returning null but I also cannot just use `IS NOT NULL` so I use `REGEXP_MATCH(Targeting Age Max, '\\d*')` instead. However, I reach the end of the line when I cannot `THEN` with `CONCAT()`.

Current progress (gives ERROR assuming because it doesn't support `CONCAT()` after `THEN`)

```sql
CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Targeting Age Max, '\\d*') AND REGEXP_MATCH(Targeting Age Min, '\\d*') THEN CONCAT(Targeting Age Min, ' – ', Targeting Age Max)
END
```

Desired result

```
25 – 45
```

Would be really cool to have a more elegant solution that doesn't require to create multiple different fields like `Targeting Age Min` and `Targeting Age Max`.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT***: The [`CONCAT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583443) formula that displays the age range in the format `age_min - age_max`:

```
CONCAT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Targeting, '"age_min":(\\d+)'), " - ", REGEXP_EXTRACT(Targeting, '"age_max":(\\d+)'))
```

Updated image of the Report with the formula:

[image: 2]]

***Original Post (Calculation): age_max - age_min***

This single calculated field uses the [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) and [`CAST`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7280720) functions to capture the values in `age_max` and `age_min`, ensures that they are both *Numeric* values and then does a subtraction:

```
CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Targeting, '"age_max":(\\d+)') AS NUMBER ) - CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Targeting, '"age_min":(\\d+)') AS NUMBER )
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/6386025f-1cd7-4f2d-a761-e76503d9f206) and GIF to elaborate:

[image: 4=5]]

Comment: Thanks for the edit. However, the reason I used `CASE` is because there are cases when either `age_min` or `age_max` are NULL (meaning the range is left open). In those cases, the original intent was to let it output "Min: age_min" or "Max: age_max" instead of the aforementioned range.

Comment: Got it; currently the `THEN` clause doesn't support expressions and formulas; so a "*Helper*" field would still need to be created (...`THEN Helper Field`....), but it would just be a single additional formula now :)